# Do I need two hot wires for a 240v single phase steamer?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm wiring a Mr. Steamer SAH6000 that is 120V/240V Single Phase. Do I need two hot wires and a ground only or do I also need a common White wire?

Comment: Downvoted because this question is answered explicitly and clearly in the product instructions.  This forum should not be used as a substitute for reading product documentation.  If you have trouble applying the instructions to your situation, or if they are unclear or seem to require more knowledge or experience than you have then ask for help here.

Comment: Reversed 1 downvote as I saw the 240 on 1 page and the 3 wire plug on another. I did not need to see anything further to know the wiring but not everyone will see everything.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is addressed in the product literature.

Comment: Note that 240V residential is still single phase. If you go to three phase, there will be talk of Wye vs. Delta. 240V vs 120V are just the line-to-line vs. line-to-neutral voltages.

Comment: Much as I see the point of everyone saying RTFM, I find myself with no choice but to agree with Ed Beal. I think the manual was clear, but the area of practice is a bit hard.

Comment: @harper I do agree with RTFM but I scanned it and missed the print when I found the specifications page it stated 240v that is clear to me as an electrician but there are many that don’t know the difference between neutral and ground.

Comment: That manual seems kind of dodgy, all the threaded parts are drawn with a left-handed thread, and apparrently the heating element draws more current at 208V than at 240

Comment: @Jasen there are two variants available of each model, one for 208V, one for >208V.  The manual is clear on that.  You have to buy the right one.  The current draw tables are for the 208V one at 208V, and the >208V one at 240V.   I think the manual is pretty good.  Nowhere in the manual is any diagram detailed enough to mislead the installer into threading something the wrong way. Where do you see that?  The instructions pertaining to actual OP are crystal clear, I've added a (mildly incredulous, sorry) Answer on that point.

Answer (score 3):

According to the installation manual:

[Installation Manual](http://static.appliancesconnection.com/attachments/D59df9130d3fdc.pdf)

[image: Wiring diagram]

This is a 240V ONLY device not 120V/240V as you have mentioned.  As such it takes 3 wires, L1, L2, and GROUND.

I strongly urge you to hire a qualified and licensed electrician for this based on your question.

Comment: I missed that print I did look in the installation materials , must have missed that print. Remember we are a diy site and this is a simple install

Comment: @EdBeal My line of thinking is that if *you* missed it, most likely so would anyone else.  Instructions can be obtuse... that doesn't make people bad.

Answer (score 3):

### Reading the instructions is mandatory...

NEC 110.3(b). You must install according to the labeling and instructions.  "Must" is not a suggestion.  In order to comply with the instructions, I trust it is fairly obvious that one needs to *read* them.

That said, if you are laying a circuit for this appliances, *there's nothing wrong with including a neutral also*.  Other appliances may be able to make good use of it.

### That thing is not "common".

Common is like a backplane where all the circuits return power.  That is fine when they are milliamp electronics circuits or the "common" is a huge steel vehicle frame.

With AC mains power, we wire both sides of the circuit coming and going.  *The neutral is the current return* and it carries the same amount of current as the hot.  **Each neutral must carry ONLY current for its partner hot(s), *or it will overload***.

Thus it is not a "common" at all, and one circuit's hot Must Not use another circuit's neutral.

Neutrals certainly can overload.  We don't put breakers on neutral because *we shouldn't have to*.  (That only works if everyone wires circuits correctly).

Comment: @ Harper do you have a neutral on your water heater?  The device states 240v there is no neutral in 240v

Comment: @EdBeal I don't claim anyone does.  I am saying neutral is neutral, and not "common".

Answer (score 2):

According to the product specifications it is 240v so 2 hot and a ground would be needed.

The only electrical I could see other than that was a 3 wire 30 amp plug so that would match with the above that it is 2 hots and a ground.

Don’t forget the GFCI breaker as code requires that now in the us.

Comment: The instructions actually say, "Neutral wire is not required" !

Comment: Did I say a neutral was required? No I said a ground only added GFCI as that is a code requirement now.

Comment: Ed, I think he was reinforcing your answer for the benefit of the asker.

Comment: Correct, I wasn't refuting your answer Ed!   I just thought it was understated and my point was intended more for OP than you. Because the question says "do I need a white wire" and the manual, which is only 13 pages including all the safety warnings, says "you do not need a white wire". :0

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to belabor the RTFM angle of the comments with a gratuitous Answer but I just had to add this picture.  The Electrical part of the instructions are *only half a page*, five simple steps.   The question is "Do I need two wires and do I need a neutral", and one of the five steps says literally and exactly, you need two wires and you don't need a neutral.

So I just don't get how this question isn't an RTFM poster child.

[image]

Comment: Because it's in the fine print, buried enough that *even Ed Beal* missed it...